# Avoid large log Jenkins file (and stop build if needed)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, diskspace

We are using Jenkins (on Linux) to manage our Maven builds.

Our users can create their own job and sometimes (3 or 4 times per year), they are doing a mistake and the job generates a large log file (79 GB the last time...).

I had a look to existing plugins and I didn't find something to monitor the Jenkins log size.

For example, if the log size exceeds 200MB (when the job is running), I would like to automatically stop the build.

If you developed such shell scripts or Jenkins plugins, can you share your solution?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [Logfilesizechecker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logfilesizechecker+Plugin):

> *This plugin monitors the size of the output file of a build and aborts the build if the log file gets too big.*

Or, if this has also an impact on the runtime, the [Build-timeout Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin):

> *This plugin allows you to automatically abort a build if it's taking too long. Once the timeout is reached, Jenkins behaves as if an invisible hand has clicked the "abort build" button.*

Comment: Thanks Gerold for your answer, the LogFileSizeChecker plugin seems interesting, I'll test it tomorrow morning on the Jenkins job log. If this plugin is able to stop the build, it will solve my issue :)

Comment: @BrunoLavit Avec plaisir ! That's why we are here. :)

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin as of Aug 4, 2017 does not support Pipeline (Workflow) jobs.

Comment: As of Dec 2017 it was updated to include Pipeline support.

Comment: Am using Logfilesizechecker plugin for Pipeline(workflow) jobs, seems like it does not abort the build even after the limit is reached.